# Yii2 - How to set dynamic authTimeout in User Identity?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Here, I have extended `User` Identity of Yii2.

This is my configuration.

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => app\models\UserMaster::class,
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'loginUrl' => ['/auth/login'],
            'authTimeout' => 86400
        ],
```

Here, I have defined `authTimout` statically. But, What I want to do is that I want to fetch timeout value from database and set it in `authTimeout`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use event to set `authTimeout` before request will be handled:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => function (Event $event) {
        /* @var $app \yii\web\Application */
        $app = $event->sender;
        $app->getUser()->authTimeout = (new Query())
            ->select('value')
            ->from('{{%settings}}')
            ->where('name = :name', ['name' => 'authTimeout'])
            ->scalar($app->getDb());
    }
],
```

---

But probably more clear approach would be to create custom component and handle this in `init()`.

```
class WebUser extends \yii\web\User {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->authTimeout = (new Query())
            ->select('value')
            ->from('{{%settings}}')
            ->where('name = :name', ['name' => 'authTimeout'])
            ->scalar();
    }
}
```

Then use new component in your config:

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => WebUser::class,
        'identityClass' => app\models\UserMaster::class,
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'loginUrl' => ['/auth/login'],
    ],
    // ...
],
```

Comment: Hi @rob006, i faced similar problem and followed the instructions as given, but somehow it's not working for me. If you can help me, it would be great for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756109/dynamic-authtimeout-not-getting-set-in-yii2 Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Probably not is the best way, but if you use autentication by cookies and have 'enableAutoLogin'=>true then go to vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php and go to the method called switchIdentity at the final of this method you should view the modify the duration time. For me it works!!!!

```
    if ($this->enableAutoLogin && $duration > 0) 
{ 

//here change the value $duration example 900 sec(15 mins) 
$this->sendIdentityCookie($identity, $duration); 
}
```